C3 bar chart looks squished when rotating axes
I have a C3 bar chart with potentially A LOT of categories on the y axis, and want the height of the graph adjust to the contents. By default, for some reason C3 seems to always set the height to 320. Manually adjusting that isn't really an option as I can't predict the number of categories. I could do the maths, count elements every time before re-drawing, figure out some formula and adjust the CSS every time - but that doesn't sound "clean" to me. I've looked around but can't find any option in the C3 config that makes sure that there's always proper spacing between the bars.


let number_of_views_list = [];
let data1 = ['data1'];
let dates = ['x'];
let i = 0;
let number_of_dates = 36;
let max_views = 100;

for (i = 0; i < number_of_dates; i++) {
  let number_of_views = Math.round(Math.random() * max_views);
  data1.push(number_of_views);
  dates.push(moment(`2019-01-01`).add(i, 'days'));
}
number_of_views_list.push(data1);
number_of_views_list.push(dates);

let ticker_dates = dates.slice(1).filter(date => date.date() === 1);

var chart1 = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    bar: {
      width: 12
    },
    data: {
      x: 'x',
      columns: number_of_views_list,
      types: { 'data1': 'bar' },
      empty: { label: { text: "No Data" } }
    },
    padding: {
      left: 50
    },
    axis: {
      rotated: true,
      x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
          count: dates / 10,
          format: '%Y-%m-%d'
        }
      }
    }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.11/c3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.9/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.7/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>



How do I make sure the bars (and legends) don't look squished?

I see someone suggested an edit - but I don't have enough reputation to see suggested edits. Please reply in comments, thanks :) Edit - worked now!

If you've got a fixed height, then setting the bar to use width: {ratio: 0.5} will stop them overlapping, but obviously they'll be a lot skinnier
Here 0.5 means the bars are half the thickness of the gaps between ticks, you can experiment with that value
However if it's the bars you want to keep constant and it's the chart you want to change, you can add a width/height config too once you've calculated what that needs to be, so you don't need to change css
https://c3js.org/samples/options_size.html
size: {
    height: data1.length * 14,
    width: 480
},

(Bear in mind you'll need the chart to be in a container that will allow the chart to resize)


let number_of_views_list = [];
let data1 = ['data1'];
let dates = ['x'];
let i = 0;
let number_of_dates = 36;
let max_views = 100;

for (i = 0; i < number_of_dates; i++) {
  let number_of_views = Math.round(Math.random() * max_views);
  data1.push(number_of_views);
  dates.push(moment(`2019-01-01`).add(i, 'days'));
}
number_of_views_list.push(data1);
number_of_views_list.push(dates);

let ticker_dates = dates.slice(1).filter(date => date.date() === 1);

var chart1 = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
     // THIS BIT
     size: {
          height: data1.length * 14,
          width: 480
     },
    bar: {
        // OR/AND THIS BIT
      width: { ratio: 0.5}
    },
    data: {
      x: 'x',
      columns: number_of_views_list,
      types: { 'data1': 'bar' },
      empty: { label: { text: "No Data" } }
    },
    padding: {
      left: 50
    },
    axis: {
      rotated: true,
      x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
          count: dates / 10,
          format: '%Y-%m-%d'
        }
      }
    }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.11/c3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.9/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.7/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>



